# Python dataframe : strip part of string, on each column row, if it is in specific format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format, strip

I have a column of values as such, on a Pandas DataFrame:

```
                column1

 google 5 8/10 07/08/74
            apple 4 1/5
       netflix 26/04/50
facebook 5 1/4 17/10/40
```

My objective would be to remove the dates, on the rows where there are dates.

What reasoning would you apply?

Find if right side of value in each row is in format xx/xx/xx, and if so delete the 8 characters on the right? Would would Python recognize the xx/xx/xx format in part of the string?

Thank you!

Comment: Use [`pd.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with a custom regex pattern.

Comment: see 2nd answer from Ubuntu